# How to deal with SQL Merge Error Msg 8672

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, sql-merge

This seems to be a very common error that most people get when working with SQL merge statements. I too have faced this many times, and usually I do find duplicate records in my source. After rectifying the issue I am good to go again.

However, it is a little different for me this time.
I am sure (and have checked many times) that I do not have any duplicate rows in my source. What I do have is duplicate ID's which make up a unique rows (but no row is the same).

For example, see attached:

RecID is Unique ID for that particular row. Circuit and service Item are 2 different tables that have been combined into one table dbo.Table1.

RecID 309 in Circuit , and RecID 309 in service are both unique within each of their source.

When I try to merge this existing table into another table I get the typical error of

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Staging.uspExample, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Can someone please help me. How do I merge dbo.Table1 into Target table without getting the error

[image]

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [Staging].[uspMergeCherwellComConfigurationItem]
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE [Cherwell].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Target]
    USING [Staging].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Source]
    ON [Source].[RecID] = [Target].[RecID]
    WHEN MATCHED AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime]) <> [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] 
    THEN
        UPDATE SET [Target].[PartitionKey] = [Source].[PartitionKey],
                   [Target].[RecID] = [Source].[RecID],
                   [Target].[ConfigurationItemTypeName] = [Source].[ConfigurationItemTypeName],
                   [Target].[CreatedDateTime] = [Source].[CreatedDateTime],
                   [Target].[Status] = [Source].[Status],
                   [Target].[CIType] = [Source].[CIType],
                   [Target].[FriendlyName] = [Source].[FriendlyName],
                   [Target].[FinancialReference] = [Source].[FinancialReference],
                   [Target].[OrganisationGroup] = [Source].[OrganisationGroup],
                   [Target].[Further_Detail] = [Source].[Further_Detail],
                   [Target].[CICount] = [Source].[CICount],
                   [Target].[unit] = [Source].[unit],
                   [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] = CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime])
                

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT
        ([PartitionKey],
            [RecID],
            [ConfigurationItemTypeName],
            [CreatedDateTime],
            [LastModifiedDateTime],
            [Status],
            [CIType],
            [FriendlyName],
            [FinancialReference],
            [OrganisationGroup],
            [Further_Detail],
            [CICount],
            [unit]
        
        )
        VALUES
        ([Source].[PartitionKey], [Source].[RecID], [Source].[ConfigurationItemTypeName], [Source].[CreatedDateTime],
         CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime]), [Source].[Status], [Source].[CIType], [Source].[FriendlyName],
         [Source].[FinancialReference], [Source].[OrganisationGroup],[Source].[Further_Detail], [Source].[CICount], [Source].[unit]);


END;
```

Comment: You did not list the code that attempts to perform the `MERGE`, making it hard for us to figure out what's going on. Would I be correct in assuming you only check for `RecID`, but somehow do not include the `unit` as part of the `MERGE` or the `JOIN`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I have added the stored proc script to the original post now. and you are correct in your assumption. I do only use RecID as part of MERGE. I did Try using other unique identifiers, Like The friendly name as part of MERGE but i started to see duplicate rows every time I executed the Merge Stored proc.

Comment: Ain't it a bit odd that RecId isn't unique in the data?  With a name like that, one would assume it's the PK, but obviously it isn't.

Comment: As for the issue, clearly you cannot use the RecID alone as a unique key, because you have overlaps between systems. If `unit` indicates the system, that should become part of the composite key that guarantees uniqueness. If you're doing data warehousing, our typical approach is to add a SourceSystem dimension, and add a reference to that in this dataset. That way you can distinguish between the overlapping rows, and easily trace the row back to its' source system.

Comment: @gumdrop - Change this: `ON [Source].[RecID] = [Target].[RecID]` to this: `ON [Source].[RecID] = [Target].[RecID] AND [Source].[unit] = [Target].[unit]`. You should then remove the unit from the `UPDATE SET` part below.

Comment: @LukStorms RecID is unique its in own source. say you have a table called Circuits and a table called service items. Circuits might have a RecID of 1,2,3 in their own respective table and Service items can have RecID of 1,2,3 in their own table. Those 2 tables have been combined in to 1 table. That table has to merge into another

Comment: So then the primary key is on `(RecId, CIType)` or on `(RecId, unit)`?

Comment: It can be on any of the other columns. (RecID, FriendlyName) , (RecID, CIType, unit, Organisation) will result in unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
MERGE [Cherwell].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Target]
USING [Staging].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Source]
ON [Source].[RecID] = [Target].[RecID]
WHEN MATCHED AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime]) <> [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] 
THEN
    UPDATE SET [Target].[PartitionKey] = [Source].[PartitionKey],
               [Target].[RecID] = [Source].[RecID],
               [Target].[ConfigurationItemTypeName] = [Source].[ConfigurationItemTypeName],
               [Target].[CreatedDateTime] = [Source].[CreatedDateTime],
               [Target].[Status] = [Source].[Status],
               [Target].[CIType] = [Source].[CIType],
               [Target].[FriendlyName] = [Source].[FriendlyName],
               [Target].[FinancialReference] = [Source].[FinancialReference],
               [Target].[OrganisationGroup] = [Source].[OrganisationGroup],
               [Target].[Further_Detail] = [Source].[Further_Detail],
               [Target].[CICount] = [Source].[CICount],
               [Target].[unit] = [Source].[unit],
               [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] = CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime])
```

to this:

```
MERGE [Cherwell].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Target]
USING [Staging].[ConfigurationItem] AS [Source]
ON [Source].[RecID] = [Target].[RecID] AND [Target].[unit] = [Source].[unit]
WHEN MATCHED AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime]) <> [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] 
THEN
    UPDATE SET [Target].[PartitionKey] = [Source].[PartitionKey],
               [Target].[RecID] = [Source].[RecID],
               [Target].[ConfigurationItemTypeName] = [Source].[ConfigurationItemTypeName],
               [Target].[CreatedDateTime] = [Source].[CreatedDateTime],
               [Target].[Status] = [Source].[Status],
               [Target].[CIType] = [Source].[CIType],
               [Target].[FriendlyName] = [Source].[FriendlyName],
               [Target].[FinancialReference] = [Source].[FinancialReference],
               [Target].[OrganisationGroup] = [Source].[OrganisationGroup],
               [Target].[Further_Detail] = [Source].[Further_Detail],
               [Target].[CICount] = [Source].[CICount],
               [Target].[LastModifiedDateTime] = CONVERT(DATETIME, [Source].[LastModifiedDateTime])
```

This basically adds the `[unit]` as part of the `JOIN`, thus ensuring uniqueness between the rows with similar `RecIds`. And seeing it now is part of the key, we do not use it in the `UPDATE` statement anymore.

Changes on line 3: The `AND [Target].[unit] = [Source].[unit]` addition to the ON clause.
Changes on line 17: Removed the line from the update).